# Chown inside docker container is not changing directory owner

Tags: docker, linux

I can't change ownership of newly created directory inside of docker container. It is not a volume and `chown` runs correctly for all my colleagues - the only difference is I'm running docker on linux while they are working on macs and windows (what should not matter, right?). My docker version: `Docker version 20.10.25, build 20.10.25-0ubuntu1~22.04.1`

I have simplified my use case to this most basic Dockerfile (php version doesn't matter, tried with 8.0 as well):

```
FROM php:7.1.33-fpm AS base
RUN mkdir /home/www-data
RUN ls -ld /home/*
RUN usermod -d /home/www-data www-data
RUN ls -ld /home/*
RUN chown -R www-data /home/www-data
RUN ls -ld /home/*
RUN chmod -R 0777 /home/www-data
RUN ls -ld /home/*
```

I run it with `docker build . --no-cache`, so there is no docker-compose used, anything cached etc.

My partial output:

```
Step 5/9 : RUN ls -ld /home/*
 ---> Running in faee10891512
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 17 08:46 /home/www-data
Removing intermediate container faee10891512
 ---> bd417136c193
Step 6/9 : RUN chown -R www-data /home/www-data
 ---> Running in 7656908de5e0
Removing intermediate container 7656908de5e0
 ---> e25a42b7f73b
Step 7/9 : RUN ls -ld /home/*
 ---> Running in e916fca31c51
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug 17 08:46 /home/www-data
Removing intermediate container e916fca31c51
 ---> be3154bf3ad6
```

Expected output (just taken from docker run on windows):

```
#8 [5/9] RUN ls -ld /home/*
#8 sha256:ab73f23a9843a55ca731c83532c9f1b95e738525c2a8437f58ed7c17d0cf245e
#8 0.457 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 17 08:40 /home/www-data
#8 DONE 0.5s

#9 [6/9] RUN chown -R www-data /home/www-data
#9 sha256:686bd64c892edc235610feb148f1a9213bdf9238e62e74f1ca87da416c97eb99
#9 DONE 0.5s

#10 [7/9] RUN ls -ld /home/*
#10 sha256:e37fbdcf3bd0ae93dd19f8bc4b81d3c22fec176a3ef6d9b957c9c46787cb79a0
#10 0.434 drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data root 4096 Aug 17 08:40 /home/www-data
#10 DONE 0.4s
```

I am really puzzled about this, anyone has and idea what should I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by removing docker completely and installing it as Docker Desktop from .deb package provided from . After that, chown started to work as it should.

Comment: This may have been an apparmor issue to begin with, can you check the contents of /etc and see if their are any scripts relevant to docker in your apparmor configs?  (I've had similar issues with selinux on Redhat derivatives)

Comment: No, I don't have anything related to docker in /etc/apparmor and subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this, instead (have not tested this):

```
FROM php:7.1.33-fpm AS base
RUN mkdir /home/www-data \
&& ls -ld /home/* \
&& usermod -d /home/www-data www-data \
&& ls -ld /home/* \
&& chown -R www-data /home/www-data \
&& ls -ld /home/* \
&& chmod -R 0777 /home/www-data \
&& ls -ld /home/*
```

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't changed the output, I have solved it with total reinstallation of docker. The root cause of the problem shall remain a mystery.